# Map not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

I have 2 maps on my site, first map is on homepage and second on contact site.
Only second map not working properly only on Google Chrome, on others browsers (Safari, Firefox) it works.

http://spelnionychmarzen.pl/kontakt/

Console throw an error in Chrome, but it isn't clear for me.

Can you help me? What else information do you need?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your google map API parameters:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAtPniL8HPtR4YcWroMGuYltVAOfSY7UBU&callback=mapcontact`.

The `mapcontact` function does not exist in browser `window` object in contact page.

The solution is creating the `mapcontact` function under `window` object, just like what you did in `mapa.js`: http://spelnionychmarzen.pl/wp-content/themes/developer/mapa.js